# Ways to import JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I understand there are several questions and articles talking about this question.

But my question is slightly different. I am using CodeIgniter framework, and it imports all of the JavaScript into the footer. Some of the JavaScript is not working for certain of pages.

**Below are my questions:**

1. Should I import my JavaScript in the page that need the script? 
   *Example: Register.php only requires `Register.js` to run the script. So, should I import     the Javascript on Register.php instead of
   footer.php?*
2. I read some articles, they suggest to use JavaScript to import other scripts instead to import all of them. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Which libraries are you importing? Could there be namespace collisions? And are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: `Should I import my Javascript on the current page that need the script? ` OFC!

Comment: Sometimes you might want to only include some scripts on specific pages, but mostly the scripts are cached, so it is minimal. Samt time you could minifiy all your scripts into a single.

Comment: @Greg Jennings
Impossible got namespace collisions. My file name is quite simple like register.js, home.js and etc. ANd there is no errors when I am using Firebug and look into the console.

Comment: @Ronni Skansing, you mean combine all the script into one?

Comment: @Drixson Osena & Derek. Changed. XD

Comment: @Blackie yea much overhead comes from the sequent http request for resources, but also meant minifying it =] search for it if you not familiar with the expression.

Comment: @RonniSkansing, thank you.
I will go to Google now. Thanks!

Comment: Np. use the minified files on the production server and use keep the originals on you development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your javascript/css/image resources in the right place will help your page load more faster because it doesn't need to load unused things.

As for me, I usually use my js like this:

`Register.php`:

- `register.js` (script to do business on register page)

`Login.php`:

- `login.js` (script to do business on login page)

`Footer.php`: (import common js library that will be used every where)

- `jquery.js`
- `jquery-validation.js`

And it will be the same with CSS and Images if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I think I should consider the loading time also. Thanks!!